# WordPress returns 404 error for existing image files from time to time

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, cloudflare

My website is using WordPress, and I use Cloudflare to cache it.

From time to time, the link checker plugin will report 404 errors on some image files. After I checking them, I find they actually exist. As Cloudflare cache the 404 page for these files, I manually clear the Cloudflare of these pages and then retry and then there will be no 404 errors.

However, after some time, there will again be 404 errors on some existing image files. So I have to repeat the process above to revalidate them.

Why there will be such a problem?

Comment: Have you actually experienced any not available images on your frontend display? How does the image upload/place upload process look like? If you're using a plugin to automatically upload images to cloudflare and link placed images accordingly – my guess would be some latency/delay is causing a 404. E.g in your editor preview trying to preview and request an remotely hosted image before it's completely uploaded and processed.

Comment: @herrstrietzel, Thank you for your comment. I check all the images that are reported as 404, and they are very old image files, such as in 2013 and 2015. They exists on our server before we starting using Cloudflare and we do not edit them recently. Also the images are uploaded via standard media library without any plugins, neither will we upload them to Cloudflare(Cloudflare will pull images when visitors need it). The only possible plugin is Imagify, which is used to optimize the images.

Comment: Pardon me – I'm still not sure I got you right. So the 404 issue occurs only with older images? If so: could it be, those older images are e.g. referenced by "http://" instead of "https://" or  with "www." opposed to your currently used scheme . In this case you could easily replace those hardcoded image src/urls with a plugin like "search replace". Maybe you should check some posts with these older images to compare the actual src output in your browser's inspector.

Comment: @herrstrietzel, THank you very much. THe page referring the image use the correct URL, i.e., https version and everything is fine. It is just for some reason that sometimes the image URL will return 404 status code, and which will be cached by Cloudflare. I use LinkChecker to check all links and find these images. If without Cloudflare, then I think LinkChecker will auto-recheck these links after sometimes and then do not report them as 404. But since using Cloudflare, the 404 error is cached for 14 days(the edge cache period set by me), so the LinkChecker think this is a permanent error.

Comment: Have you tried to disable Broken Link Checker and flushing all caches? (Actually Link checker puts quite a load on your server and tries to fix way too much). Disabling imagify for some time might also be worth a try since it can manipulate image output quite drastically e.g by jpg to wepP conversions. Are there other plugins with caching methods involved (cache enabler, autoptimize etc.)?

Comment: @herrstrietzel, OK. I will try to disable Broken Link Checker. But without it, how can I know whether there are broken links in my website? For cache plugin, I use WP Rocket.